# How to get my postbacks with multi-word payloads to work?

Tags: smooch

I can't seem to get my postbacks containing multi-word payloads to work. I've set up multiple postbacks such as

`%[PD Site](postback:PD_SITE)`

`"PD SITE":"...`

All of my postbacks like the one above return "I didn't understand that"

https://github.com/greeleyblteam/EstherBot/blob/master/script.json

Comment: Can you edit your post to add the actual code related to the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please put the actual code snippet I had to go through your commit history to figure out the issue.*

The problem seems to be because of the way [EstherBot](https://github.com/esthercrawford/EstherBot/blob/42617b24165ebadf3b0743ed8c6b4a70441e328f/heroku/index.js#L113) was (oddly) coded. It's actually the button label that it sent *as a reply*. If you were to use this postback button:

```
%[Sure!](postback:multi_word)
```

This would be fine usually; having *multiple words* isn't related to your issue and that would work under regular circumstances. When the user clicks on the postback, the bot is [actually listening](https://github.com/esthercrawford/EstherBot/blob/42617b24165ebadf3b0743ed8c6b4a70441e328f/heroku/index.js#L113) to `Sure!` instead. Which didn't have any entry in your [script.json](https://github.com/greeleyblteam/EstherBot/blob/master/script.json).

To fix your issue, you can add an entry for `SURE!`

```
%[SURE!](postback:multi_word)
"SURE!":"...
```

or rename the label to `MULTI WORD`.

```
%[MULTI WORD](postback:multi_word)
"MULTI WORD":"...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm still learning, so this is all new to me. Thanks for the tip in adding my actual code snippet